# Add different images to UIImageView of cells in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

Needless to say, i am a novice. I am trying to add images and text to a UITableView. I have been able to add the text but I am having problems with adding different images to the desired text.

I have 2 separate PHP codes for 1 database:

- The first gets the text and an id for the image assigned to the text (imageID)
- The second uses the id (from the first PHP) to acquire the image

My code is fine but **currently only 1 image is appearing for all the text**

My question is **how do I assign each image to their text ?**

And how do I not assign an image to the text that do not have images as some of the texts don't have images with them?

**My code is as follows:**

*Connection and data download:*

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Create an array to store the locations
        NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Parse the JSON that came in
    NSError *error;
    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    // Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to our questions array
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

        // Create a new cell object and set its props to JsonElement properties
        if (![jsonElement [@"Thought"] isEqual:[NSNull null]])
        {
            NSString *listText =jsonElement [@"Thought"];
            if ([listText length] > 0)
            {
                NSString *cellText = jsonElement[@"Thought"];
                [list addObject:cellText];
                NSLog(@"list Cell: %@", cellText);
            }

            if (![jsonElement [@"filename"] isEqual:[NSNull null]])
            {
                imageID = jsonElement[@"id"];
            }
            NSLog(@"Cell Image: %@", imageID);
        }
    }
    [[self tableView1] reloadData];
}
```

*Cells in the table:*

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleIdentifier = @"SimpleIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:20];

    if ([imageID length] > 0)
    {
        urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://database.name/getimage.php?id=%@", imageID];
        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
        UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        cell.imageView.image = imageLoad;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not leave any case untouched in `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. What happens when you try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleIdentifier = @"SimpleIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:20];

    if ([imageID length] > 0)
    {
        urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://database.name/getimage.php?id=%@", imageID];
        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
        UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        cell.imageView.image = imageLoad;
    }
    else //I assume this is the case when a row does not contain an image right?
    {
        cell.imageView.image = nil; //Or the below line for better aestethics
        //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderimage.png"];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

By the way `NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];` is called everytime `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is triggered and this happens alot. As far as I know `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is a heavy process and stalls the UI until it downloads the image. So it would be better to download one specific image once and save it in a `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableDictionary`. For instance:

```
//in your .m
@interface ViewController ()

@property NSMutableDictionary * imageIdDictionary;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageIdDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

And change your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to:

```
//Added this. You need a second array just like `list` which has all the different imageID's stored
imageID = [list2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([imageID length] > 0) {
    if([self.imageIdDictionary objectForKey:imageID]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [self.imageIdDictionary objectForKey:imageID];
    }
    else {
        urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://database.name/getimage.php?id=%@", imageID];
        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
        UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        cell.imageView.image = imageLoad;
        [self.imageIdDictionary setValue:imageLoad forKey:imageID];
        //added these two lines!!!!!!!
        NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]];
        [table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
else {
    cell.imageView.image = nil; //Or the below line for better aestethics
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderimage.png"];
}
```

This will make your application run much smoother

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The table loads faster but it is still the same image for all the cells

Comment: Where do you store your `imageID`s? `imageID = jsonElement[@"id"];` Do you store this in an array? And How do you get `imageID` in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? Can you post more code, especially the lines about `imageID` and the Array it is stored in..

Comment: Also, I added two more lines of code to reload the cells whose images are downloaded.

Comment: Do I need to store imageID in an array?, I want the cell attached to each text to send a request to download the image using the imageID. I gather I have to put imageID in an array but how will i ensure it does not get printed as text and each image is with it's correct text

Comment: Yes, just like you did in connectionDidFinishLoading: [list addObject:cellText]; you should have similar code: [list2 addObject: imageID]. And in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: you should get the true imageID from list2. I added that code to the beginning

Answer (score 1):

UITableView's cells are reusable. It means that the cells which are not visible will show the same content before you reset.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleIdentifier = @"SimpleIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    cell.imageView.image = nil;

    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:20];

    ...
}
```

Just add the reset codes.